# Python/ElementTree: Write to file without namespaces

Tags: python, html, xml, namespaces, elementtree

I'm trying to write an ElementTree object to disk. Everything works, except that the output file looks like this:

```
<html:html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html:head>
<html:title>vocab</html:title>
<html:style type="text/css"> ...
```

Since it's got the `html:` namespace info, the browser can't render it.

**How can I make etree save some html to disk without the `html:` namespace info?**

Here's the code I'm using to write:

```
with open('/path/to/file.html', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
mypage.write(outfile)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've got it working, but with a kind of roundabout method.

I'm getting a string for the tree (with `etree.tostrng()`), and then using `re.sub('html:', '', thetext)` to remove the namespace info. Then, I just write the string to disk normally.

Answer (score 9):

I've been using this workaround:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
ET.register_namespace('', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
```

Then the `html:` prefix will be replaced with whitespace when outputting.